# How do i configure .gitlab-ci.yml to build my django project

Tags: django, yaml, gitlab-ci

I have succesfully installed and configured gitlab and gitlab-ci-multirunners. What i want to do now is configure the .gitlab-ci.yml file so that it runs `python manage.py test` and succeed if the tests pass and fail otherwise.

What would be the best approach to achieve this?

Answer (score 7):

```
test_app:
  script: python manage.py test
```

Something like the above should do it. Note, the exit code of the `script` command determines if the build passes or fails. If you need multiple lines of shell scripts you can use a yaml list:

```
test_app:
  script:
    - python dosetup.py
    - python manage.py test
```

`test_app` is the name of the build job while the `script` property defines the shell commands to run for the given build job. When using multiple script lines, each line is run as a separate command. If any of the lines return exit code != 0 the build will fail.

By default a build job in `.gitlab-ci.yml` runs as test. If you need multiple types of build steps you can define them as such:

```
types:
  - build
  - test

build_app:
  type: build
  script: echo Building!

test_app:
  type: test
  script: python manage.py test
```

More info in the official documentation: https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/

Comment: any help with coverage badge?